# Как ограничить работу скрипта(jquery) в пределах div?

Tags: html, jquery

Есть html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        ...
        <script>должен работать в пределах своего div</script>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        ...
        <script>должен работать в пределах своего div</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть в div-блоке `parent` много одинаковых div-блоков `child`, в которых также есть блоки с одинаковыми id, class.(`child` является шаблоном, который копируется с помощью скрипта). Нужно, что бы методы jquery (find, on) работали только в своём div-блоке.

Comment: _есть блоки с одинаковыми id_ - это недопустимо, id должен быть уникальным на странице

Comment: Скорее всего Вы где-то не туда свернули. Выглядит так, что вы используете разные, либо повторяющиеся скрипты для решения одинаковой задачи. Если это так, то лучше подумать о том как использовать один скрипт для всех этих задач (DRY).

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы хотите реализовать, проще всего сделать с помощью $('.parent > .child:nth-child(n)'), где n - порядковый номер дочернего блока внутри родительского. Но я рекомендую присвоить каждому из child индивидуальный id и обращаться по нему. Также помните, что одинаковых id на странице быть не должно